# Brackets editor is running slowly on Meteor project

Tags: performance, meteor, adobe-brackets

I use the Brackets editor on a Meteor project and it runs very slowly when the Meteor server is launched.
I already tried to reload Brackets without extensions but it didn't change anything.
When Meteor server is stopped Brackets runs normally.
Is there a way to make Brackets run normally with Meteor server on?

Comment: could you show how you use the editor in your project? I suspect that there is some sort of reactive loop going all the time, but without looking at some code to reproduce this behavior it will be hard to say.